# I'm having trouble with python arrays, my two-dimensional (array of arrays) has a per-row offset

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I cannot for the life of me spot why each row has additional leading 0's.

The array aiWalls[] defines x/y coordinates that should be a '1' in the resulting array of arrays (2 dimensional array?) wallTable[].  Any coordinates in the same wallTable[] that do not have a matching pair in aiWalls[] should be a 0.

Python:

```
aiWalls = [(25, 25), (25, 75), (25, 125)]
wallTable = []
tileX = 0
tileY = 0
row = []
tableSizeX = 200
tableSizeY = 200
while tileY < tableSizeY:
    tileX = 0
    #row = [] #new row
    while tileX < tableSizeX:
        pos = (tileX,tileY)
        for node in aiWalls:
            if node[0] == pos[0] and node[1] == pos[1]:
                print("wall found @ " + str(pos))
                row.append(1) #add 1 to the row
                #print(row)
            elif node[0] != pos[0] or node[1] != pos[1]: 
                row.append(0)
        tileX = tileX + 25
    tileY = tileY + 25

    wallTable.append(row)
    row = []
for scan in wallTable:
    print(scan)
```

Output:

```
wall found @ (25, 25)
wall found @ (25, 75)
wall found @ (25, 125)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I'm going to keep futzing with this periodically and if I solve it, I'll answer with the corrections... If you can figure it out, I would really appreciate an explanation of where I've goofed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time through your inner loop, you're adding 3 values to the current `row` rather than just one, because you're looping over the three elements in `aiWalls` each time.

I assume that what you want to do is check the three positions in `aiWalls` against the current position inside your loops.  If one or more of them match, then you want to add a `1`, else you want to add a `0`.

Here's a modified version of your code that does that:

```
aiWalls = [(25, 25), (25, 75), (25, 125)]
wallTable = []
tileX = 0
tileY = 0
row = []
tableSizeX = 200
tableSizeY = 200
while tileY < tableSizeY:
    tileX = 0
    while tileX < tableSizeX:
        pos = (tileX,tileY)
        for node in aiWalls:
            if node[0] == pos[0] and node[1] == pos[1]:
                print("wall found @ " + str(pos))
                row.append(1)
                break
        else:
            row.append(0)
        tileX = tileX + 25
    tileY = tileY + 25
    wallTable.append(row)
    row = []
for scan in wallTable:
    print(scan)
```

The use of `for/else` is a bit advanced.  The `else` clause will be executed if the inner loop ran to completion never executing `break`.

Results:

```
wall found @ (25, 25)
wall found @ (25, 75)
wall found @ (25, 125)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Wow...  I knew I had overlooked something simple.